# simple PHP contact form returns 500 internal server error

Tags: php, forms, submit, contacts

Im trying to implement a simple form for visitors to contact me by. Im using php (Im a very beginner) and am having problems that it is returning 500 internal server error. The form displays fine and everything, its just when i press submit that it happens. the form is at [This page](http://www.huntinghall.co.uk/website2013cottages/ContactUs)

The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail('tburn76@gmail.com', $subject,
  $message, 'From:' . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email : <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'  value='Send'>
  </form>";
  }
?>
```

Many thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is a problem in your hosting provider. 500 is a server error not
>   a programming but you should do this before

change your seconde echo to this

```
  echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' name='email'>
  Email : <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit' name='email' value='Send'>
  </form>";
```

the code will be

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail('tburn76@gmail.com', $subject,
  $message, 'From:' . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' name='email'>
  Email : <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit' name='email' value='Send'>
  </form>";
  }
?>
```

PS : i think that is not a code error but this will help you 
good luck !

Comment: Thanks!! That works! Only problem now is the email address field dosen't seem to be sent with the email. Just some "Send@cpanel54.uk2.net" email regardless of what i put into the box.
Any thoughts?
Many thanks,
Tommy

Comment: ok dont miss to vote ----- change mail function to   mail('tburn76@gmail.com', $subject,
  $message, 'From: Alpha RooT <' . $email.'>'); change alpha root to any name you want :D am here for any question edited

Comment: Ok. thanks thats really helpful, However now the sent email address is showing as  Alpha RooT or whatever i put in there. how do i show what was in the $email variable?

Comment: change the seconde echo to this
  echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' name='email'>
  Name : <input name='name' type='text'><br>
  Email : <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit' name='email' value='Send'>
  </form>";   and add a linge below line 8 with thid    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;   and change mail function to   **mail('tburn76@gmail.com', $subject,
  $message, 'From: '.$name.' <' . $email . '>');**